# Is there a shortcut for importing all weights of a Google font?

Tags: css, google-fonts

In a CSS file, I'd like to @import all weights and styles of a google font, say Roboto or Roboto Slab, for experimentation. Later I can trim to a list of only needed styles. Is there a shortcut, rather than putting the entire list in the @import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this `:wght@100..900`

or `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Khula:wght@100..900" rel="stylesheet">`

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately there's no way for that, you need to import one by one. You may try import the font by media link setting the weights you want after the font name as follows:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Khula:400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
```

Note: Web fonts can really slow down your site, try to import only what is needed.

Comment: I want to include these fonts on several pages, so I was thinking of using @import in custom.css (a style sheet which all pages link to). If I use the <link> method do I have to insert all the font <link>s on every page that uses them? (Meaning redudant code, but I also guess it means a chance to trim the links specifically by page, and speed up page loading)

Comment: Supposing you are using a framework, you may put this that inside the mains layout file. But if you're using less code, you can just import inside your main CSS file.

Comment: What is the "mains layout file"?

Comment: A framework allows you wrap your code with layouts. Take a look:
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#layouts